# Firefox and IE browser events always stuck one event behind

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, firefox

I've got a strange situation with my Firefox and IE browsers on my work machine where it seems as if the events such as text selection and mouse overs are stuck one behind whatever the current event should be.

An example would be if try to select a sentence of text, the text selection will stop short of the end of the sentence by 1 character.

Another example would be if you had a navigation bar on a web page with drop down menus that display their contents upon mouse over, if I run my cursor over the first two drop down menus and leave it on top of the 2nd drop down menu, only the 1st drop down menu will display, when it should be the 2nd. But if i then move my curosr to the 3rd drop down menu, the 2nd will display.

This isn't a development question so much as it is a browser behaviour issue.

I've had similar problems like this in the past where anti virus software was being overly aggressive towards google chrome but we no longer have that software (McAffee I think it was). Could it be this again?

We're currently using Symantec Endpoint Protection, could this be causing these issues? Again though google chrome is operating fine but FF is slow and IE is horrendously slow and occasionally dies a horrible death when some remotely complicated JS is executing in a web page.

Also I've disabled just about every plugin I can find in all browsers with only minor performance gains for disabling the Flash plugin.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes seem to have the same problem with FireFox on OSX after suspend-resume.

I can force it to update if bring another window in front and then re-expose Firefox.